# MSI: Why do we need to write the line back when other CPU is going to override it?

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

In the book "Computer Architecture", by Hennessy/Patterson, 5th ed, on page 360 they describe MSI protocol, and write something like:

> If the line is in state "Exclusive" (Modified), then on receiving "Write Miss" from the bus the current CPU 1) writes back the line into the bus, and then 2) goes into "Invalid" state.

*Why do we need to write-back the line, if it will be overwritten anyway by the successive write by the other CPU?*

Is it connected with the fact that every CPU should see the same writes? (but I don't see why is it a problem not see this particular write by some other CPU)

Here is the protocol from their book (question in green, in purple it is clear: we need to write-back in order to supply the line to requesting CPU):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing back the modified data to memory is not strictly necessary in a MSI protocol. The state diagrams also seem to assume a system with low cost memory access (data is supplied by memory even when found in the shared state in another cache) and a shared bus connecting to the memory interface.

However, the modified data cannot simply be dropped as in shared state since the requesting processor might only be modifying part of the cache block (e.g., only one byte). Whatever portions of the block that are not modified by the requesting processor must still be available either in memory or at the requesting processor (the other processor has already invalidated its copy). With a shared bus and low cost memory access the cost difference of adding a write-back to memory over just communicating the data to the other processor is small.

In addition, even on a word-addressed system with word-sized cache blocks, keeping the old data available allows the write miss request to be sent speculatively (as with out-of-order execution or prefetch-for-write) without correctness issues.

(Per-byte tracking of modified [or valid as a superset of modified] state would allow some data communication to be avoided at the cost of extra state bits and a more complex communication system.)

Comment: Amazing. This is not written in the book. Thanks! Just a note: "data is supplied by memory even when found in the shared state in another cache" -- the diagram is not clear for this case. But in the book they have a [table](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/444947/posts/stackoverflow_cache_coherency_msi.jpg) and in there: `if ReadMiss on the bus and state is Shared/Modified then _attempt to _share data: place cache block on bus` -- looks like data is supplied by the cache, not by the memory.

Comment: @Ayrat Textbook authors have to manage trade-offs of accuracy and completeness vs. ease of communication and simplicity (and time-to-market), so eliding some information is normal. Sadly, some simplifications can make understanding *more* difficult. (Incidentally, source-from-memory can be desirable for some directory-based coherence systems, especially when the directory is co-resident with the data in memory so the memory access is free. Such can reduce the hop-count [latency] to the requester and reduce use of interconnect bandwidth.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is just about the L1-L2-LLC or L1-LLC relationships.

We have to write-back Modified data, because we'll go to shared state and LLC transmits shared state cache lines. But if you don't write this data to back, you have to get S stated data from another cache.

If you ask about why we don't just serve the S stated cache line by another cache, think about you have a S stated address in Core1-l1D,Core2-l1D,Core3-l1D.

If Core 4 wants to load this data and Core4-l1D doesn't have the data, Core4-l1D will issue a kind of request signal as getShared.

First problem is which one going to response? You can not choose which one will response this request until you go through it and read the tags. So each l1D cache will give response to this request.

Second problem, lets say you don't care about the power consumption and efficiency on timing. The problem here is, that causes unnecessary bus traffic. Because it is obvious to say that other 3 core will respond to this request at the same cycle.

By summarizing, we get S stated cache lines from LLC, because trying to get them from other caches cause more traffic on bus and total bus latency in your system. And if you get S stated cache lines from LLC, you have to write back to dirty data to LLC.