# Cache MOSI protocol: why a block should supply data when a write miss occurs

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, mesi

I was reading *Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach* and I was confused by the following paragraph (version 5 - Page 415):

"
A common protocol optimization is to introduce an Owned state (usually denoted O). The Owned state behaves like the Shared state, in that nodes may only read Owned blocks. But it behaves like the Modified state, in that nodes must supply data on other nodes’ read and write misses to Owned blocks. A read miss to a block in either the Modified or Owned states supplies data to the requesting node and transitions to the Owned state. ***A write miss to a block in either state Modified or Owned supplies data to the requesting node*** and transitions to state Invalid. This optimized MOSI protocol only updates memory when a node replaces a block in state Modified or Owned.
"

My question is: why the old data should be supplied to the requesting node when a write miss happens?

Efforts I have made: I read one related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194540/msi-why-do-we-need-to-write-the-line-back-when-other-cpu-is-going-to-override-i). I don't quite understand the answer for that question, especially "*keeping the old data available allows the write miss request to be sent speculatively (as with out-of-order execution or prefetch-for-write) without correctness issues.*" But I still think that my question is different since the old data is not written back to memory but to the requesting node (Should be cache, I guess?).

Comment: Writes aren't full-line writes; they need a "read for ownership" first and then commit the new data into one part of that cache line.  A full-line write *could* just invalidate other copies without waiting for old incoming data.

Comment: [MESI protocol. Write with cache miss. Why needs main memory value fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39180919) explains why a core doing a store needs to old value of the line in the first place.  Getting it from another cache instead of from memory is the optimization that the O state allows, but your real question is answered by that duplicate.

Comment: Thank you! It is very helpful :)